# AsyncTask: Is onPostExecute guaranteed to run after all calls to onProgressUpdate?

Tags: android, background, backgroundworker, android-asynctask

I would like to know if it is possible to get 'leftover' calls to `AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate` after `AsyncTask#onPostExecute` has been called? I am setting text on the same `TextView` using both of them, and I don't want to set text such as "Done!" and then have it overwritten at a later point by text such as "Almost there - 90%"

Also, I am assuming that the `onProgressUpdate` method works similar to a `SwingWorker` method in that multiple calls to `publishProgress` may stack up before a call to `onProgressUpdate` occurs. I would really like to know where the "newer" and "older" progress updates are on the parameter - aka are the newest updates at position 0 in the parameter, or at position `progress.length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code to `publishProgress` is:

```
protected final void publishProgress(Progress... values) {
    sHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_POST_PROGRESS,
            new AsyncTaskResult<Progress>(this, values)).sendToTarget();
}
```

The `sendToTarget` call uses `Handler#sendMessage` which the docs say "pushes the message onto the end of the message queue." I understand that to mean that you will not get any out of order updates and that they will stack up. Also, for each `publishProgress` call there will be a corresponding `onProgressUpdate` call.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for taking the time to look this up! Guess it doesn't work the same way as the SwingWorkers :)

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I'm sorry but I will answer it regardless of the previous answer : 
YES, you are guaranteed that onPostExecute() will be invoked AFTER all calls to onProgressUpdate().

Why? Because the doInBackground is responsible for invoking onProgressUpdate(), so it can't happen outside of it. onPostExecute() is invoked after the result has been retrieved, since it does transmit it to onPostExecute()

Regards

Comment: I don't believe it is guarenteed..do you have any documented support for your claim? This post suggests otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219115/asynctask-never-executes-onpostexecute

Comment: Of course I didn't mentioned it but here it is:  it is guaranteed in all cases BUT the one in wich a cancel was called in between.  In that particular case, onPostExecute is simply never invoked. OnCancel is called instead. That's what your link is about.

Comment: Yep. But wouldn't that mean that onPostExecute is not guaranteed to be invoked after all calls to onProgressUpdate?