# AsyncTask never executes onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to execute the following AsyncTask :

```
private class TimeUpdateTask extends AsyncTask<List<mObject>, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<mObject>... params) {
            mObject o;
            int i;
            int numChecked = 0;

            List<mObject> mObjects = params[0];
            while(true)
            {   
                if (isCancelled())
                {
                    Log.w("TAG", "task interrumped");
                    return null;
                }

                    for (i=0 ; i < mObjects.size() ; i++)
                    {
                        o = mObjects.get(i);
                        if (!o.isChecked())
                        {
                            o.calculateProgress();
                            if (o.isChecked())
                            {
                                numChecked++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                publishProgress(numChecked);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... param){
            int progressCompleted = param[0];

            ((ArrayAdapter<mObject>) EventListView.this.EventView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

            mMain.setProgressBarCompleted(progressCompleted);
        }

        /*This should execute*/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.d("TAG","End onPostExecute");
         }

    }
```

So when I call `cancel(false)` on this task, `onPostExecute` should be executed but it never is.

Is there any problem in the code or something else?
I have looked at a lot of answers in SO and it seems that having #5 `AsyncTask` hanging around is normal, even if you are using only one (as in my case) at the moment.

Comment: Further to other comments / answers - don't use `while(true)`. Try `while(!isCancelled())` - it makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks ,I was thinking the same:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is 1 large piece missing here that you must learn about.

from the developer docs (see bold text below): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if
>   the task has already completed, already been cancelled, or could not
>   be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has
>   not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If the
>   task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter
>   determines whether the thread executing this task should be
>   interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.
>
> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked
>   on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. **Calling
>   this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked.**
>   After invoking this method, you should check the value returned by
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the
>   task as early as possible.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out .Now everything makes more sense :)

Comment: "Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked." - exactly why the OP never sees the `onPostExecute(...)` method being called. +1

Answer (score 3):

Android use onCancelled() when the task is cancelled, it don't call onPostExecute!

Answer (score 2):

I think calling cancel actually cancels everything from executing, including the onPostExecute. You should use your own local boolean variable and do this:

```
private boolean shouldContinue = true;

public void customCancel() 
{
       shouldContinue = false;
}
```

then in your loop do this:

```
if (!shouldContinue)
{
    Log.w("TAG", "task interrumped");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense - by the time `onCancelled()` is called the `doInBackground(...)` method will already have terminated and `shouldContinue` has no relevance in 'the loop'.