# onPostExecute executes before doInBackground in Asyncronous task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

After searching for a long , i went through the following links and understood ,

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29)

[AsyncTask never executes onPostExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219115/asynctask-never-executes-onpostexecute)

But i want to do some API hits to the server and after getting all the data , i want to move to my mainactivity from the Splashscreen , below is my code . .  . .

```
class Startsyntask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
    {

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
         { 
            raw_data = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.MyFoldernew");
            if(raw_data.exists())
            {
                Log.e("directory exists", " already ");
                new read_syntask().execute();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("directory created", " newly ");
                raw_data.mkdirs();
                new write_syntask().execute();
            }
            return null;    
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
         {
             if( i == 6)
             {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.sample.app.Tabbar"));
             }
         }
    }
```

and in the code `read_synctask` and `write_synctask` are another asyncronous tasks that has some specific operations to do with , in these Asyncronous tasks it is calling the onPostexecute after doinBackground .

Actually it moves to the Tabbar Activity and the API hits continues and i get data read from server in Tabbar activity . how could i implement that only after completing the asyncronous task in doinBackground , onProgress should be called .

Comment: You can try to put the startActivity in the onPostExecute  in the read_synctask and write_synctask as one of them has to complete before you navigate to the next activity. And WHY are you using two async tasks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,

```
new read_syntask().execute();
```

and

```
new write_syntask().execute();
```

both have **Asynchronous call** which don't wait for complete the task and perform the next execution step, so your execution comes to `onPostExecute()` before finishes both `AsyncTask`.

What you have to do is,

use   `new read_syntask().execute().get();` and `new write_syntask().execute().get();`

Now `get()` method from `AsyncTask` will wait for complete the AsyncTask and then `onPostExecute()` will execute. (But I think it will block the UI thread).

**Update:** (Best approach)

Actually, there is no need of `Startsyntask`  AsyncTask, You can directly write the **if-else conditions** of `raw_data` in Activity's method and also your code for starting `Tabbar`

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent("com.sample.app.Tabbar"));
```

should be in either `read_syntask` or `write_syntask` 's `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: @Anukool - yeah I knew, Both AsyncTasks are called in `doInBackground()`. And also to wait for complete Asynctask you have to use `get()` method.

Comment: I am still unable to understand the use of two Multiple AsyncTasks.

Comment: @Anukool - As its OP's Programming approach, we can't say anything without seeing entire code. We have to give answer, according to question and posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting "how could i implement that only after completing the asyncronous task in doinBackground , onProgress should be called ."

I don't know much. But maybe using Handler can help.  Send a message after the onPostExecute of the asynchronous task and on handleMessage of your handler, do what you want to do.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html